Mono.block() after Flux.collectList() vs List.map() after Mono.block(), memory leak occurs in the former
In the process of implementing batch jobs in Spring Batch and Spring WebFlux environments, OOM occurred. We also confirmed memory leaks through heap memory graphs, etc.
While looking for the cause of the memory leak, I removed the part that used ReactiveMongoTemplate and found that the memory leak did not occur. Accordingly, we tested a number of cases and found the following conclusions:

CustomStudentRepository: Custom repository created using ReactiveMongoTemplate
Student: Entity
chunk.times: List<Mono<Student>>

Mono.block() after Flux.collectList()

fun write(chunk: Chunk<out Mono<Student>>) {
        Flux.concat(chunk.items)
            .flatMap { customStudentRepository.upsert(it) }
            .collectList()
            .block()
    }



List.map() after Flux.block()

fun write(chunk: Chunk<out Mono<Student>>) {
        Flux.concat(chunk.items)
            .collectList()
            .block()!!
            .map {
                customStudentRepository.upsert(it)
                    .block()
            }
    }


Memory leaks only occur in the former case(1. Mono.block() after Flux.collectList()).
Why does the memory leak occur only in the former case?

I tried using the ReactiveMongoRepository implementation instead of ReactiveMongoTemplate, but the result was the same.


Do you need this list for the fist sample? If not, can you try without collectList()?

First of all i dont understand why you are using block in a reactive application, if the application is the final consumer you should be using subscribe and not block. Second, the two code examples are different, why are you doing a collect list after the first upsert, while you are collecting a list, then mapping over the list and blocking on each insert in the second example. You are comparing two completely differnt scenarios.

@Toerktumlare This code is used by Spring Batch. Unfortunately, Spring Batch does not support Reactive Programming, so we need to block the batch thread, so we called block() explicitly.

@IgorArtamonov I tried using blockLast() instead of collectList().block(), but I got the same heap memory graph (memory leak) as number 1.

@Toerktumlare Both examples are scenarios where multiple Student received in Mono format are stored in MongoDB. The former processes upsert() by tying it into one reactive stream and calls block() at the end, while the latter calls block() in the middle and calls block() once more after upsert()(Note that upsert() returns Mono).

if you need to run blocking code, there is a section in the docs talking about it, you need to place the code on its own scheduler so it gets assigned its own thread, if you are blocking you might get extreme performance issues, as the blocking code will basically halt everything in your application until the blocking is released https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking do not use block use subscribe.

Lets say the storing suddenly takes 1 second. Depending on the numbers of cores in your system, but lets say you have 2 cores, during that 1 second 50% of you application will stand still for 1 second. So for one second you will have half the performance in your application because that code is waiting for the database.

@Toerktumlare First of all, thank you for your reply.
That batch job is performed within a Pod, independent of any other batch job or service application, via CronJob in Kubernetes. Therefore, it is meaningless for a thread to be blocked due to block() (an application that exists from the beginning to only perform batch operations).
Also, as mentioned earlier, if you use subscribe() instead of block() in Spring Batch, the batch thread will terminate before all actual work is completed.

@Toerktumlare What's important to me now is not performance and speed, but why I don't have a memory leak in number 2, unlike number 1.

Im just pointing out that its very hard to diagnose your memory leak with the small amount of code given and the fact that the code is not written according to best practices. So good luck

The main difference between this two examples is that the first makes multiple upserts in parallel, and the second executes them one by one. I don't know if that is the cause of the leak, but you can configure the parallelism for the first code: .flatMap(customStudentRepository::upsert, 1) (or a bit higher number). Also I would suggest to use then() for the both cases, b/c especially with collectList it creates unnecessary intermediary objects which may be hard to GC

Might be related to prefetch, could you try the same using .concatMap instead of .flatMap, and/or play with prefetch value (third argument of .flatMap and second argument of .concatMap).
